# Why there are more than one "still running" instances

Tags: linux, reboot

I'm checking a server's reboot history by `last -x reboot`, the output is as following:

```
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Tue Sep 24 00:21   still running
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Fri Sep 20 07:48   still running
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Fri Sep 20 01:11 - 23:55  (-1:15)
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Thu Sep 19 23:28 - 17:17  (-6:10)
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Wed Sep 18 20:12 - 15:34  (19:21)
```

Why there are two `still running` instances? According to my understanding, there should one and only one `still running` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last` reads the file `/var/log/wtmp`. Normally when shutting down a system a record will be written to this file indicating this fact; the same happens when booting a system to record the boot moment.

In your case apparently the shutdown record wasn't written to the file the last time, so `last` can't find the shutdown record matching the booting record, and writes "still running" as that is usually the case in such a situation.

I have seen the Debian version of the `last` command show "crash" in such situation, perhaps that the Fedora version thinks that's too alarming as there could possibly be other reasons for the missing record.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me. But why record wasn't written to the file? Can I just empty the log file to make `last` statement works as before?

Comment: The wtmp file is usually rotated every month, so the discrepancy will resolve itself in a few days.